# Saving preferences & data before doing clean install of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, thunderbird

I am currently running Firefox & Thunderbird/Lightning in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I wish to do a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a clean install of Firefox & Thunderbird/Lightning preserving ALL my preferences & data from 16.04.

I do a complete backup (via luckyBackup) of the "Home" folder every time I log on.

Which folder/files should I check for to ensure that I can reload my preferences & data?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to have copies of `.mozilla` and `.thunderbird`, the two hidden directories in the home folder that hold the profiles of Firefox and Thunderbird respectively.

To see the hidden files, use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut.